Fixed Effects model "within" "individual" adding time dummies
Currently I am writing my thesis about the influence of natural resource dependence on child health.
I have an unbalanced panel dataset with 117 countries from 2002-2020. I use the code under the question provided.
When i'm conducting a two-way fixed effect model, controlling for both time and country fixed effects, my R2 becomes really low (0.115). However in this example my independent variable of interest (NRR3) is in predicted direction and significant. Some of my control variables are however not in the expected direction. One of my robustness checks (important to answer my research question) is perfect in this case.
When i'm conducting a individual fixed effect, with country fixed effects, every variable is in the expected direction, but my independent variable is not significant anymore. My R2 is 0.550.
I expect there to be significant changes over the years (since it is priority of for instance SDGs to decrease mortality rates). I have included time dummies in my country fixed effects model and my r2 is now 0.8, but it gives me the exact same coefficients and standard errors as the two way model. Im trying to make sense of this and try to find empirical literature to confirm this way of thinking, but unfortunately i can not find this for now.
What does including a time dummy do in a country fixed effect model compared to a two-way fixed effect model? Is this something that could be confirmed by empirical literature?
And a minor question: i found out after conducting my fixed effect model that there is still heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation in my data, im now doing HAC standard errors, is this a good thing? Do i still have to cluster my standard errors? Code provided below.
TWO LAGS INCLUDED
###Fixed effect model: main analysis
FEMA2 <- plm(formula = MU52 ~ NRR3_lag2 + MVAA3 + REER2 + CEPI3 + GE2 + COC2 + EYS + PM2.52 + TE2 + CHE2, data = MD2, index = c("State", "Year"), model = "within", effect = "individual")
stargazer(FEMA2, type = "text")
#HAC Standard Errors (FE)
vcov_hac_FEMA2 <- vcovSCC(FEMA2, type = "HC1", maxlag =7)
stargazer(FEMA2, type = "text", se = list(sqrt(diag(vcov_hac_FEMA2))), title = "Main Analysis (FE) (2 lags) with HAC Standard Errors", align = TRUE)
